# can I manually choose to get data from response cache or from server in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am new in using Alamofire and iOS development in general. I am fetching data from server using the code below

```
func getDataFromServer(completion: @escaping ( _ dataString: String) -> Void) {
        
        
        let url = "http://app10.com/index.php/Data"
        let parameters : [String:Any] = ["someData": "xxx"]
        AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers:nil).responseJSON { (response) in
            
            switch response.result {
            
                case .failure(let errorResponse) :
                    
                    let errorMessage = "error message here: \(errorResponse.localizedDescription)"
                    print(errorMessage)
                    completion("")
                    
                case .success(let value) :
                    
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    let dataString = json["data"].stringValue
                    completion(dataString)
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

as you can see from the code above, I am trying to get `dataString` from server. but what I want to achieve is something like this

```
if meetSomeCondition  {
    // get 'dataString' from response cache from alamofire
} else {
    // fetch 'dataString' from server, using the code above
}
```

can I do something like that using only alamofire?

I am sorry, I am newbie, but I can do something like that if I use Firebase Firestore, so maybe alamofire has feature something like that

I have tried to search but I can't find it in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

The underlying URLSession utilises a URLCache. Ensure your URLSession uses a URLCache and your server uses an appropriate response to instruct the client to cache the response.

In order to get the cached response, if any, the method according HTTP would be to set a cache control request header:

`Cache-Control: only-if-cached`   (see [RFC 5.2.1.7 only-if-cached](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1))

That is, you would need to set this additional header when you create the request. Then execute the request as usual and you would either get the cached response or a status code 504 if there is none. Exactly what you would need.

Now, when you try this you realise, it unfortunately won't work as expected (bummer!). The reasons for this is manifold and it would be futile to go into detail.

The approach you may try next is to set the cache control policy of the URLRequest as follows:

`urlRequest.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataDontLoad`

You can look up the meaning of it here: [returnCacheDataDontLoad](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/cachepolicy/returncachedatadontload)

Please read the documentation and the source documentation as well *carefully*, since it's not implemented in every iOS version!

That seems to be a working solution, however when using Alamofire you need to access the underlying URLRequest in order to set the cache policy (you may search on SO how to accomplish this) - and you need to be sure Alamofire does not alter your cache policy under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

`Alamofire` does not provide cache directly.

It is easy to achieve it yourself.

use `NSCache` to keep our memory footprint low,

use time stamp, to invalidate stale data

here is an example:

```
// by writing a thin wrapper around NSCache, we can create a much more flexible Swift caching API 
// — that enables us to store structs and other value types, and let us use any Hashable key type 

final class Cache<Key: Hashable, Value> {
    private let wrapped = NSCache<WrappedKey, Entry>()
    private let dateProvider: () -> Date
    private let entryLifetime: TimeInterval
    

    init(dateProvider: @escaping () -> Date = Date.init,
         entryLifetime: TimeInterval = 12 * 60 * 60) {
        self.dateProvider = dateProvider
        self.entryLifetime = entryLifetime
    }

    func insert(_ value: Value, forKey key: Key) {
        let date = dateProvider().addingTimeInterval(entryLifetime)
        let entry = Entry(value: value, expirationDate: date)
        wrapped.setObject(entry, forKey: WrappedKey(key))
    }
    
    
    func value(forKey key: Key) -> Value? {
        guard let entry = wrapped.object(forKey: WrappedKey(key)) else {
                return nil
        }
        guard dateProvider() < entry.expirationDate else {
                // Discard values that have expired
            removeValue(forKey: key)
            return nil
        }
        return entry.value
    }

    func removeValue(forKey key: Key) {
        wrapped.removeObject(forKey: WrappedKey(key))
    }
}


private extension Cache {
    final class WrappedKey: NSObject {
        let key: Key

        init(_ key: Key) { self.key = key }

        override var hash: Int { return key.hashValue }

        override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
            guard let value = object as? WrappedKey else {
                return false
            }

            return value.key == key
        }
    }
}



private extension Cache {
    final class Entry {
        let value: Value
        let expirationDate: Date

        init(value: Value, expirationDate: Date) {
            self.value = value
            self.expirationDate = expirationDate
        }
    }
    
    
}


extension Cache {
    subscript(key: Key) -> Value? {
        get { return value(forKey: key) }
        set {
            guard let value = newValue else {
                // If nil was assigned using our subscript,
                // then we remove any value for that key:
                removeValue(forKey: key)
                return
            }

            insert(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

call like this:

```
// global singleton

let cache = Cache<Int, Int>()
// ...
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        cache.insert(5, forKey: 1)
        print(cache[1])
    }
```

Persistent caching is also easy.

use `Codable` to do serialize the data.

use `FileManager`  to persist the data file to disk